# Categorize matrices such that each column has $c$ nonzero entries and each row has $b$ nonzero entries

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, discrete-mathematics

I would like to understand all matrices (including those which are nonsquare) which obey the following properties:

- Each column contains the same number $c$ of nonzero elements
- Each row contains the same number $b$ of nonzero elements

For any such matrix I understand that the number of rows $s$ and the number of columns $a$ must obey the constraint $$ac=bs$$ When $c=1$ the solution matrix configuration takes the form of a modified identity matrix in which each column is duplicated $b$ times (an s×(nb) matrix), and when $b=1$ the same is true except there are instead $c$ duplicates of each row (an (sc)×n matrix).

It is also clear that given a solution matrix with parameters $a,b,c,s$ one may easily find another solution $a,a-b,s-c,s$ is also a solution matrix.

I understand that there may be more than one solution for a given pair $b,c$. For example, $a,b,c,s=4,3,3,4$ and $a,b,c,s=7,3,3,7$ both have $b,c=3,3$. One way to differentiate between these two solutions is to recognize that in the one with $a,s=4,4$ each row contains non-zero elements in 2 columns that each other row contains non-zero elements. That is, any pair of rows "overlaps" by exactly two columns in which they both contain non-zero elements. Call this the overlap number $d$. While $a,b,c,d,s=4,3,3,2,4$ and $a,b,c,d,s=7,3,3,1,7$ are solutions,
$a,b,c,d,s=4,3,3,1,4$ and $a,b,c,d,s=7,3,3,2,7$ are not.

If $$n=\sum_{i=1}^{s-1}$$ then $c,d=2,1$ is a solution.

Also, the tuplets $a,b,c,d,s=n,n-1,n-1,n-2,n$ correspond to square matrix solutions which may be represented with a first row of $n-1$ 1s and one 0, with each of the subsequent $n-1$ rows a cyclic rotation (by one element) of the previous.

Is there a way to determine whether or not a given triplet $b,c,d$ (or $$a,s,d$$ $$a,c,d$$ $$b,s,d$$ or . . . ) is a valid solution without simply testing the triplet to see if it will provide a solution? Perhaps there is an algebraic relationship related to the prime factors of these values which one can use to generate all valid solutions. Any information would be greatly appreciated.